# How to idle a C program

Tags: c, windows, operating-system

I wrote a CPU intensive program in C to run on Windows. In the main loop I check for a keyboard press to allow you to interrupt execution in order to pause the program. The idea is to release the thread to other processes if the program is slowing down the computer too much. After a keyboard press I wait for more keyboard input using fgets(), which allows you to restart the program later. This does reduce the CPU usage shown in task manager quite well. But I was wondering if there is perhaps a more explicit way to tell the operating system that this process doesn't need any attention for a while in order to reduce the overhead while idle to the absolute minimum.

My understanding is that the operating system periodically lets a process run and then stops running it after a certain amount of time. It then checks the rest of the processes in the same way until it comes back to this one again. If it has enough to do the process will run for the maximum allowed time. Otherwise, it will stop early and return control to the operating system. So a function like fgets must immediately return control if there is no keyboard input, which is why the process runs at near 0% CPU. So I guess another way of asking my question is how do I deliberately return control to the operating system in my own code.

Comment: Perhaps just set a low priority for your thread?

Comment: In general, you should offload the CPU-intensive work to another thread, (maybe at a reduced priority), and handle the user interface in your 'main thread', (especially if the main thread is handling a GUI).  Your work thread could poll an atomic 'pause' boolean, (much faster than a KB I/O poll) and, if set, wait on an event or semaphore synchro until the main thread resets 'pause' and signals the synchro.

Comment: Solutions requiring repeated system calls are wasteful and unnecessary, those using timeouts worse.  There is no need to do any more in your CPU-intensive task loop than to test an atomic boolean to see if set.

Comment: If an answer has helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

> my question is how do I deliberately return control to the operating system in my own code

You can use either `Sleep(0)` or `SwitchToThread()`. Both pass control back to the OS and might cause the calling thread to give up the remaining time slice but the devil is in the detail.

**Sleep(0)**

If no other thread with a matching priority is ready to run, the call returns immediately. Otherwise, the thread gives up its remaining time slice.

You can work around the priority issue by using `SwitchToThread` or `Sleep(1)`. The disadvantage of the latter is that the thread gives up its time slice unconditionally, whether or not other threads are ready to run.

**SwitchToThread()**

If no other thread, irrespective if its priority, is ready to run on the thread's current processor, the call returns immediately. Otherwise, the thread gives up its remaining time slice for at most one time slice.

Alternatively, you could change the priority of the process (`SetPriorityClass()` with `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN`) or thread (`SetThreadPriority()` with `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN`) so that the OS can take care of prioritizing more important processes/threads for you. In your scenario, doing so would be a better fit. The scheduler will respond to sudden CPU demand without any additional work on your end.

Comment: Another thread handling the UI would be more effective.  Polling an atomic boolean is very quick.  Repeated  system calls are not necessary to meet the needs of the OP.

Comment: We don't know if a UI is involved. In any case, there's no need for repeated system calls. Idle priority ensures that the application will only use the CPU is ready to run. The part about `Sleep` and `SwitchToThread` answers the question, though.

Comment: polling the KB is a UI, albeit a simple one.  Lowering the priority is certainly a partial solution - maybe all the OP needs if manual control of execution is not needed:)

Comment: My understanding is that the current solution is merely a workaround to deal with situations where the scheduling of more important threads is blocked by the application - I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pretty much two ways. Either read the input using a blocking function, like `fgets`, or read the input using a non-blocking function. In the second situation you would need to incorporate a timeout of some sort. Some functions do this for you, like `select`. Otherwise you need to regularly sleep your process or thread.

Effectively the system is using interrupts to determine which processes care about a specific event.

Comment: No, this is bad design:(